# Count characters in a string without spaces

Tags: counting

I am trying to count the characters without the spaces.
Here is my code:

```
word = 'Ricardo Cadenas'
def string_lenght(word):
    count = 0
    for char in word:
        count = count + 1
    return count - word.count('')
print(string_lenght(word))
```

my out put is-1 ??? any ideas?

Comment: just as an FYI ... this `string_lenght(word)` has the word `length` misspelled. you may want to fix that since it is truly distracting. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. I think you meant to put `word.count(' ')` but you put `word.count('')` (no space.)
Also instead of looping to calculate `count`, you can initialize `count = len(word)`.

Comment: Yours is a simplified solutions, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Correct, changing “” to “ “ should do the trick!